# Another NVL with date

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Below is a sample SQL question regarding NVL.

Examine the structure of the PROGRAMS table.

```
CREATE TABLE programs (prog_id NOT NULL NUMBER(3),
                       prog_cost NUMBER(8, 2)
                       start_date NOT NULL DATE,
                       end_date DATE
                       );
```

Which two SQL statements would execute successfully? (choose two.)

```
A) SELECT nvl(add_months(end_date, 1), SYSDATE)
from programs;

B) SELECT to_date(nvl(SYSDATE - end_date, SYSDATE))
from programs;

C) SELECT nvl(months_between(start_date, end_date), 'ongoing')
from programs;

D) SELECT nvl(to_char(months_between(start_date, end_date)), 'ongoing')
from programs;
```

To me, as long as the data in the programs table is not given, all the above four statements can be executed successfully.

The correct answers are A & D. There is no explanation to the answer. Does anyone know how did the author arrive at A & D.

Answer (score 2):

B and C have some issues with logic. And infamous implicit conversions too.

```
B) SELECT to_date(nvl(SYSDATE - end_date, SYSDATE))
from programs;
```

Expression `SYSDATE - end_date` will give you the interval between two dates. As it is numeric value, the result will have `NUMBER` datatype. Second parameter (`SYSDATE`) is `DATE`. And while implicit conversion may actually help to avoid exception and give you some kind of numeric result, I don't really get, why would anyone need the current date converted to number. Seems pretty useless.

```
C) SELECT nvl(months_between(start_date, end_date), 'ongoing')
from programs;
```

Ok, I can imagine some kind of a case for it, although I would probably do it differently, but implicit conversion again.

> `MONTHS_BETWEEN`
>   ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm))
>   returns number of months between dates.

So first parameter has a `NUMBER` datatype. Passing `'ongoing'` string as a second parameter should raise *Invalid number* exception unless you have some really weird NLS parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for A and D as the answers come down to mis-matching data types in the `nvl` function. Both arguments must be of the same type.

```
with test_data as
(
    select 1 as prog_id, 1 as prog_cost, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy') as start_date, sysdate as end_date from dual
    union all
    select 2, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), sysdate from dual
    union all
    select 3, 1, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
    union all
    select 4, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
)
select nvl(add_months(end_date, 1), sysdate)
from test_data;
```

The above executes and returns results for all records...

```
with test_data as
(
    select 1 as prog_id, 1 as prog_cost, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy') as start_date, sysdate as end_date from dual
    union all
    select 2, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), sysdate from dual
    union all
    select 3, 1, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
    union all
    select 4, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
)
select to_date(nvl(SYSDATE - end_date, SYSDATE))
from test_data;
```

The above throws an error `ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month` because the two arguments of `nvl` are not of the same data type...

```
with test_data as
(
    select 1 as prog_id, 1 as prog_cost, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy') as start_date, sysdate as end_date from dual
    union all
    select 2, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), sysdate from dual
    union all
    select 3, 1, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
    union all
    select 4, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
)
select nvl(months_between(start_date, end_date), 'ongoing')
from test_data;
```

Like the previous one, the above throws an error `ORA-01722: invalid number` because the two arguments of `nvl` are not the same data type. `months_between` returns a number and `'ongoing'` is a varchar...

The last one works because it converts the return of `months_between` into a `char`...

```
with test_data as
(
    select 1 as prog_id, 1 as prog_cost, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy') as start_date, sysdate as end_date from dual
    union all
    select 2, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), sysdate from dual
    union all
    select 3, 1, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
    union all
    select 4, null, to_date('10-12-2015', 'MM-dd-yyyy'), null from dual
)
select nvl(to_char(months_between(start_date, end_date)), 'ongoing')
from test_data;
```

Comment: It would help if you included the full error messages in your answer, not just the error numbers.